# Poincaré inequality, bounded norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be open and bounded. For any $u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$, define
$$
\|u\|:=\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} .
$$

How can I show that there exist $C_{1}, C_{2}>0$ (independent of $u$) such that
$$
C_{1}\|u\| \leq\|u\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)} \leq C_{2}\|u\|
$$

**My attempt:**

Because of the Poincaré inequality, there is a constant $C$ with
$$
\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} \leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} \quad \forall u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)
$$
It follows for $u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega) \subset H^{1}(\Omega)$ that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|u\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)} &=\left(\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\right)^{1 / 2} \leq\left(C\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\right)^{1 / 2} \\
& \leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} \leq C\|u||_{H^{1}(\Omega)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Is this correct? How do I show the full inequality?

Comment: This has completely nothing to do with sobolev space, but just basic inequality: when $a, b\ge 0$, you want to bound $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ by $a+b$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your approach were correct, you would be proving the inequality only on a subspace of the Sobolev space, hence not getting the correct result.

If I understood well you are proving the equivalence of the following two norms in $H^1$:

$$
\|u\|:=\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} .
$$

$$ \|u\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)} =\left(\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\right)^{1 / 2} $$

I would not use Poincaré inequality here, but only the same strategy you use to prove equivalence between euclidean norm and taxi-cab norm (or of $p$ norms in finite dimensional spaces) (let me give you a hint below)

> Use Hoelder inequality.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more? How would I use Hoelder?

Comment: Another reasoning: Since you know that both are Banach spaces with their norm, and one is easily seen to be $\geq$ than the other, then by the open mapping theorem applied to the identity, they are equivalent.

Comment: How would I use the open mapping theorem here?

Comment: to prove equivalence of the norms. For more details, even if you should try yourself first (in the general case), look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315952/norm-equivalence-sobolev-space)

Comment: If we use Holder's we have $\left|\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}\right| \leq\left(\left|\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\right|^{2}\right)^{1 / 2} n^{1 / q}$. What would be n and q? n=2 and q = 2?