# Show equivalence of 2 specific norms in sobolev space

Tags: normed-spaces, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I have this problem:

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a bounded open set. Let $u\in\mathbb{W}_2^{(5)}(\Omega)$

$$
\| u \|_1 = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq 5} \| \mathcal{D}^\alpha u \|_{L_2(\Omega)}
$$

and

$$
\| u \|_2 = \left( \sum_{|\alpha| \leq 5} \int_\Omega | \mathcal{D}^\alpha(x)|^2 dx\right)^\frac{1}{2}
$$

As you can see $\|u\|_1$ is a norm from the sobolev space. I'm supposed to show equivalence between these 2.

To prove that I need to show that there $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a\|u\|_2 \leq \|u\|_1 \leq b\|u\|_2$

I managed to show the first inequality but I can't figure out the second one. I found a similar question asked in an even more general case [Norm equivalence Sobolev space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315952/norm-equivalence-sobolev-space) but I can't figure out how to use the advice given there.

Comment: If we only had a sum with two terms, say $a,b$, we could estimate $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\geq \sqrt{a^2}=\vert a\vert.$$ Thus, doing the same for $b$, we get $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\geq (\vert a\vert +\vert b\vert)/2.$$ Now use this with your sum and the terms being squares of $L^2$-norms.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Cauchy-Schwarz for sums.

Answer (score 1):

This really is just a trivial consequence of equivalence of norms in finite dimensions. In general, say we're considering $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega\subset\Bbb{R}^n$. Define $N$ to be size of the set of multindices $\{\alpha\,:\, |\alpha|\leq k\}$; this is a positive integer depending on $k$ and the dimension $n$.

For each $u\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, let us associate the vector $\tilde{u}\in\Bbb{R}^N$, defined as $\tilde{u}=\left(\|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\right)_{|\alpha|\leq k}$. In words, given the Sobolev function $u$, we look at all the weak derivatives $D^{\alpha}u$, take their $L^p$ norm, and arrange these numbers into a tuple in $\Bbb{R}^N$ (the order is irrelevant). Now, the space $\Bbb{R}^N$ is finite-dimensional, so all the norms on it are equivalent. We can now define the Sobolev norm of the function $u$ to be any norm of the associated tuple $\tilde{u}\in\Bbb{R}^N$. So, for example, on the space $\Bbb{R}^N$, you can consider the $\ell^q$ norm:
\begin{align}
\|u\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega);\,\ell^q}:=\|\tilde{u}\|_{\ell^q(\Bbb{R}^N)}=
\begin{cases}
\left(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}\|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}^q\right)^{1/q}&\text{if $q\in [1,\infty)$}\\
\max\limits_{|\alpha|\leq k}\|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}&\text{if $q=\infty$.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Your first example used $(n,k,p,q)=(2,5,2,1)$ while your second example used $(n,k,p,q)=(2,5,2,2)$.

Now, we can go further and say that there's nothing special about the $\ell^q$ norms on $\Bbb{R}^N$, and that we could simply consider an arbitrary norm $\rho$ on $\Bbb{R}^N$, and simply define
\begin{align}
\|u\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega);\,\,\rho}&:=\rho(\tilde{u}).
\end{align}
Since $\Bbb{R}^N$ is finite-dimensional, any two norms $\rho_1,\rho_2$ on $\Bbb{R}^N$ are equivalent, and consequently, the associated norms $\|\cdot\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega);\, \rho_1}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega);\, \rho_2}$, first of all, really are norms on $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, and secondly, they are equivalent (in fact, if $c\rho_1\leq \rho_2\leq C\rho_1$, then $c\|\cdot\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega);\, \rho_1}\leq \|\cdot\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega);\, \rho_2}\leq C\|\cdot\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega);\, \rho_1}$).

If the above is still too abstract, then you should start off by proving that the $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$ norms on $\Bbb{R}^N$ are equivalent (this is a very elementary exercise, for which you don't need any abstract results (and the proof idea is already there in the comments)).