# A question on equivalent norms on Sobolev spaces

Tags: normed-spaces, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $p \in [1,\infty)$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded region. Consider the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

Then, by definition, any $f \in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ has all weak derivatives up to the order $k$ and they are all in $L^p(\Omega)$. It is a Banach space with the norm
\begin{equation}
\lVert f \rVert_{k,p}:= \Bigl( \sum_{ \lvert i \rvert \leq k} \lVert f^{(i)} \rVert_{p}^p \Bigr)^{1/p}
\end{equation}

However, I wonder if the following norm is equivalent to above $\lVert f \rVert_{k,p}$:
\begin{equation}
\lVert f \rVert'_{k,p}:=\sum_{ \lvert i \rvert \leq k} \lVert f^{(i)} \rVert_{p}
\end{equation}

At least $\lVert f \rVert'_{k,p} < \infty$ is equivalent to $f \in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$. However, I do not see how $\lVert f \rVert'_{k,p}$ and $\lVert f \rVert_{k,p}$ are equivalent on $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315952/norm-equivalence-sobolev-space) question

Comment: If you just want a hint. Try to prove that both norms are equivalent to the norm $\max_{\vert i\vert \leq k} \Vert f^{(i)}\Vert_p$.